# CakePHP 2.4 pagination sort on I18n translated field

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.4

I'm using SmoothTranslate Behavior for CakePHP. Its uses Cake's TranslateBehavior.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/sky_l3ppard/2010/01/05/smoothtranslate-to-make-smooth-translations

I have a Model wich contains contents ("Content").
I have fields what are translated, so i have an I18n model too.

When i'm tring to sort by a Translated field like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('I18n__title.content',__('Title')); ?>
```

The paginator component drops this because the I18n__title is a automatic generated alias for the translated field, and not an alias of teh model ("Content").

PaginatorComponent line 396:

$correctAlias = ($object->alias == $alias);

$object->alias is "Content" but the $alias of the column is "I18n__title".

The whole code of PaginatorComponent:

```
foreach ($options['order'] as $key => $value) {
            $field = $key;
            $alias = $object->alias;
            if (strpos($key, '.') !== false) {
                list($alias, $field) = explode('.', $key);
            }
            $correctAlias = ($object->alias == $alias);

            if ($correctAlias && $object->hasField($field)) {   
                $order[$object->alias . '.' . $field] = $value;
            } elseif ($correctAlias && $object->hasField($key, true)) {
                $order[$field] = $value;
            } elseif (isset($object->{$alias}) && $object->{$alias}->hasField($field, true)) {
                $order[$alias . '.' . $field] = $value;
            }
        }
```

Can the CakePhp 2.x sort by a translated field?

Comment: In this state of CakePhp you cant sort bay translated fields, maybe Cake 3.0 will contain this future in new translation model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. On the controller method you should have a call to the paginator component like this:

```
$articles = $this->paginate();
```

You need to change it to something like this, adding I18n__title.content to the whitelist parameter like this:

```
$articles = $this->paginate(null, array(), array('I18n__title.content', ... other fields you wanna sort must also be added));
```

This way you avoid it to be deleted on the query as a non recognized field in the model (check validateSort method on PaginatorComponent)